# Round up numbers so it is divisible by m (in R)

Tags: r, rounding

What is the easiest way to round up x  so that it is divisible by m ?

---

For example,

```
if x = 114, m =4, then the round up should be 116
```

or

```
if x = 119, m=5, then the round up should be 120
```

Answer (score 5):

```
roundUp <- function(x,m) m*ceiling(x / m)
roundUp(119,5)
roundUp(114,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide the number by the require multiple, round the result to the next integer and multiply again by the required multiple.

E.g.: 116 / 5 = 23.1, round to 24, 24 · 5 = 120

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo (%%):

```
roundUP <- function(x, m){x + m - x %% m}

roundUP(114, 4)
[1] 116
roundUP(119, 5)
[1] 120
roundUP(118, 5)
[1] 120
roundUP(113, 5)
[1] 115
```